# Something that has a "name and description"

Tags: single-word-requests

This is for programming, a variable name.

I have been thinking and searching and cannot come up with anything. I need a single (non-obscure) word that implies having a name, and description. Ex:

The Foo Name
And this is the description part. Goes on and on...

What would I call that pair?

Comment: I'm grasping a bit. What do you want to distinguish this well-defined pair  from? Something without a name? Would 'defined' do?

Comment: @Bookeater I want to distinguish that pair from the normal. What I have is a "name" and a "description" following. To work, though, I need a single word that implies that there is a "item" with name and description of some type. Thinking now, item may work, is there any other word, though?

Comment: That would be a combination of 'named' and 'described'. 'Specified' is the closest I can come up with linguistically. But you may have more use for a technical term.

Comment: **Entity** is commonly used in Object Oriented design. It is "a thing worthy of a name".

Comment: Can you name it based on the concrete idea, rather than the abstract "name-description / key-value pair" concept that you describe? For instance, if this is the name of a person and their description, call it Person. If this is the name of a book and its description, call it Book. Or is it something more abstract than that?

Comment: I would call it a "thing".

Answer (score 3):

Generally, things have names. It's pretty common. As such, I'd recommend calling it `describable`, modified to fit your language's conventions.

Note also that this might be a symptom of bad programming practices -- generally, if you have something so vague you're struggling to come up with a word for it, you need to step one level down the abstraction tree and be more concrete.